# Symfony2 Functional Test returns error

Tags: symfony, functional-testing

I using functional test for some controller action. Controller render twig template which use Service with Dependency Injection.

But when I execute test I receive an error: `Resetting the container is not allowed when a scope is active.`

What the problem?

```
services:
    ad_backend.menu:
        class: AdBackendBundle\Services\MenuService
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @request_stack, @router, @twig]
```

Twig config:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        service_menu: "@ad_backend.menu"
```

In twig:

```
{{ service_menu.renderMenu({name: 'menu', visible: true})|raw }}
```

Test code:

```
public function testMenus()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/backend/menu/list');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

    $this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(0, $crawler->filter('.block-menu-list')->count());
}
```

Full an error output:

```
Resetting the container is not allowed when a scope is active.
 /home/voodoo/Dev/server/ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:360
 /home/voodoo/Dev/server/ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:182
 /home/voodoo/Dev/server/ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:192


Resetting the container is not allowed when a scope is active.
 /home/voodoo/Dev/server/ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:360
 /home/voodoo/Dev/server/ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:182
 /home/voodoo/Dev/server/ad/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:192
```

Comment: `assertGreaterThanOrEqual(0,` This test will always be true, there will always be `>= 0` elements. Please add the full error stack in your question by **edit**ing it.

Comment: Assert doesn't have metter. Problem in container shutdown.

Comment: Your menu service doesn't appear to be a Controller action - it takes the request stack and probably does some other things with the container, maybe even generates a brand new request?  It sounds like there's a conflict there.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I just ran into this error as well. In [my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588695/sf2-functional-tests-resetting-the-container-is-not-allowed-when-a-scope-is-a), my test is fully empty and the error pop at client creation (when resetting container). The only scoped service present in container is request.